# chroot /bin/bash not found. How to fix without mounting /lib?

Tags: linux, bash, mount, chroot

I want to chroot into an environment but it doesn't work since it says /bin/bash is not found. I don't know why, the host is running the same Linux image and arch.

I made it working by mounting /lib and /lib64 to /mnt/ but I want to use yum in my chroot and need the original lib to install new packages.

Answer (score -1):

`# cp -n /lib64/* /mnt/lib64/` worked nicely